# Catching error on angular is producing success and error result at the same time

Tags: angular

Im calling a service on my app, which works fine, later I was trying to show some errors in case something wrong happens.. So I create this on my component

**myComponent.ts**

```
this.apiService.signUp(formData).subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
  
    if (res.error) {
      console.log("Error here!");
    } else {
      console.log("User signed up!");
      this.router.navigate(['/security/login']);
    }
});
```

**apiService.ts**

```
  signUp(payload) {
    const url = `${this.restService.url.user.signUpUser}`;

    return this.httpClient.post(url, payload)
      .pipe(
        map((body: any) => body),
        catchError((err) => of('Error, could not signed up the user: ', err))
      );
  }
```

And this is what I get at the console...

```
User signed up!
Error here!
```

Both result "!?" Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: That's why the router. navigate is redirecting probably to the same page and that observable runs again. Please check how many times you run that subscription in the OnInit method.

Comment: @Dody I've deleted that line, same result. My OnInit doesn't have anything inside.

Comment: are you sure you are not firing twice? try adding tap(val => console.log("triggered")) in your apiService.ts to verify its only triggered once

Comment: You are cathing your error into your service, there is no need to check res. error, because you are sure that you are getting the right result

Comment: @RebaiAhmed that makes sense, I guess I should add an interceptor and let the component clean.